# how to allow use : (colon) in path in apache on windows

Tags: php, apache, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on a Telegram bot on localhost via wamp server.

We know that all new updates come from a url like this (contain sepecific token of that bot) :

```
/123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/webhook
```

As you can see the path is include a `:` character that is not allowed on windows (according to this [bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41441)) and each time update sent to that url below error occured in apache :

```
[Fri Jan 12 12:15:53.736344 2018] [core:error] [pid 6488:tid 956] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:53595] AH00127: Cannot map POST /123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11/webhook HTTP/1.1 to file
```

But I could not found any solution for this problem.

Do you know any path or simple solution ?

I'm working on windows 8 64 bit and using Apache 2.4.23 - PHP 7.0.10.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to use bot token in webhook url is make sure request is from Telegram.

You can use base64 encoded token, or `/webhook?Token=<token>` instead.

Comment: how to use base64 ? I tried `/webhook?Token=<token>` and setted it but in this case update does not send updates

Comment: Updates comes from telegram but an `419 unknow status` occures that I do know how can I see details.